# How to create and secure multi-auth api gurds using laravel 8 passport?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I'm building an API for android app which requires 2 types of authentication using Laravel 8. Users Auth and Teachers Auth.

The problem that I have is that tokens which are created for users can be used in teachers api requests while they must not work in teachers routes. if someone copied the token of a user can change the user's data.

I made some changes to the auth.php :
I added this to the guards:

```
 'teacher_api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'teacher',

        ],
```

```
'guards' => [
        'teacher' => [
            'driver'   => 'session',
            'provider' => 'teachers',
        ],

        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
        'teacher_api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'teachers',

        ],
    ],
```

The providers array:

```
 'providers' => [
        'teachers' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model'  => App\Teacher::class,
        ],

        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

    ],
```

The Api Routes:

```
    Route::prefix('teacher')->group(function () {
        Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:teacher_api'], function () {
            Route::get('teacher_info', 'Api\ApiController@teacherInfo');
            Route::post('update_teacher_info', 'Api\ApiController@updateTeacherInfo');
        });
    });
```

What step did I forget to do ?

Comment: Did you miss to define `Passport::routes` method within the boot method of your `AuthServiceProvider`?

Comment: @sta no I didn't miss that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone was looking an answer related to my question.

1. If you're using laravel 8.x. Don't try to install sfelix-martins/passport-multiauth package. The package is deprecated because Laravel Passport has a native implementation since version 9.0.
2. Try reading these articles. Each of them perform multi-guards with passport scopes and hope you find the solution that you need as I did.

The Articles:

[Laravel 8 Multi Authentication API Tutorial](https://www.nicesnippets.com/blog/laravel-8-multi-authentication-api-tutorial)

[How to setup Multi-Auth for Laravel APIs | by Toby Okeke | Medium](https://medium.com/@toby.okeke/how-to-setup-multi-auth-for-laravel-apis-cb4203d3d82e)